# How to avoid NoMethodError for missing elements in nested hashes, without repeated nil checks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

I'm looking for a good way to avoid checking for `nil` at each level in deeply nested hashes. For example:

```
name = params[:company][:owner][:name] if params[:company] && params[:company][:owner] && params[:company][:owner][:name]
```

This requires three checks, and makes for very ugly code. Any way to get around this?

Comment: In groovy you would use the `?` operator. Actually i'm interested by an equivalent operator. You can still extend the hash class and add the operator.

Comment: @Pasta [Io](http://iolanguage.com) has a similar operator, but Ruby does not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced [a method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) on both `Hash` and `Array`.

```
name = params.dig(:company, :owner, :name)
```

It returns `nil` if the key is missing at any level.

If you are using a version of Ruby older than 2.3, you can install a gem such as `ruby_dig` or `hash_dig_and_collect`, or implement the functionality yourself:

```
module RubyDig
  def dig(key, *rest)
    if value = (self[key] rescue nil)
      if rest.empty?
        value
      elsif value.respond_to?(:dig)
        value.dig(*rest)
      end
    end
  end
end

if RUBY_VERSION < '2.3'
  Array.send(:include, RubyDig)
  Hash.send(:include, RubyDig)
end
```

Comment: `params.dig` will fail if `params` is `nil`. Consider using the safe navigation operator instead or combined with `.dig` as: `params&.dig(:company, :owner, :name)` or `params&.company&.owner&.name`.

Comment: The syntax of the safe navigator operator on hashes in my previous comment is incorrect. The correct syntax is: `params&.[](:company)&.[](:owner)&.[](:name)`.

Answer (score 11):

The best compromise between functionality and clarity IMO is Raganwald's [`andand`](https://github.com/raganwald/andand). With that, you would do:

```
params[:company].andand[:owner].andand[:name]
```

It's similar to `try`, but reads a lot better in this case since you're still sending messages like normal, but with a delimiter between that calls attention to the fact that you're treating nils specially.

Comment: +1: I was going to recommend maybe's Ick (also from Raganwald), which is the same idea, you can also include a link in the answer: http://ick.rubyforge.org/

Comment: IMO `andand` is syntactically disgusting

Comment: @mpd: Why? In concept or you just don't like that particular word?

Comment: @chuck I like the concept, but it seems very un-elegant. It also is confusing if you don't know what it is being used for, I mean `andand` just doesn't make sense(I understand the reference to `&&`). I don't think it properly conveys it's meaning with it's name. That being said, I like it better than `try`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if that's what you want, but maybe you could do this?

```
name = params[:company][:owner][:name] rescue nil
```

Comment: sorry to say that but indiscriminate rescues are evil, you can mask so many non-related errors...

Comment: Yes, EEEEeeevil with a capital "E".

Comment: Since the only thing happening here is hash lookups with symbols, this seems to me like a very discriminate rescue, and exactly what I do.

Comment: You may select the exceptions you want to catch, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224875/equivalent-of-try-for-a-hash/17686902#17686902

Comment: @glennmcdonald This code by no way ensures that `params` is a hash. `rescue nil` is still a no-go. There're better, effortless solutions posted here. There's no reason to take the risk and try to be smart about this.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** This answer is way out-of-date. Use `dig` as the current accepted answer suggests.

If it's Rails, use

```
params.try(:[], :company).try(:[], :owner).try(:[], :name)
```

Oh wait, that's even uglier. ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is uglier. Thanks for the response Kyle.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into one of the ways to add [auto-vivification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) to ruby hashes. There are a number of approaches mentioned in the following stackoverflow threads:

- [Ruby Autovivification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541019/ruby-autovivification)
- [ruby hash autovivification (facets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503671/ruby-hash-autovivification-facets)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I'd never heard of *auto-vivification* before but it would be perfect if I was defining the hash. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: how about editing your answer and making the links more apparent. It's hard to tell what the last two point to.

Answer (score 4):

Equivalent to the second solution that user `mpd` suggested, only more idiomatic Ruby:

```
class Hash
  def deep_fetch *path
    path.inject(self){|acc, e| acc[e] if acc}
  end
end

hash = {a: {b: {c: 3, d: 4}}}

p hash.deep_fetch :a, :b, :c
#=> 3
p hash.deep_fetch :a, :b
#=> {:c=>3, :d=>4}
p hash.deep_fetch :a, :b, :e
#=> nil
p hash.deep_fetch :a, :b, :e, :f
#=> nil
```

Comment: A slightly improved method is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224875/equivalent-of-try-for-a-hash#6225321

Comment: And a slightly more improved than 'slightly improved' method is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27498050/199685

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna get into monkeypatching you could do something like this

`class NilClass
  def [](anything)
    nil
  end
end`

Then a call to `params[:company][:owner][:name]` will yield nil if at any point one of the nested hashes is nil.

EDIT:
If you want a safer route that also provides clean code you could do something like

`class Hash
  def chain(*args)
    x = 0
    current = self[args[x]]
    while current && x < args.size - 1
      x += 1
      current = current[args[x]]
    end
    current
  end
end`

The code would look like this: `params.chain(:company, :owner, :name)`

Comment: I like this solution because it's clever and leads to really clean code. But boy it sure feels dangerous to me. You'll never know if an array is actually nil throughout your entire app.

Comment: Yeah, that is a big downside to this approach.However, there are some other tricks that can be done within the method definition to warn you when this occurs. It's really just an idea, one that can be tailored to the programmers needs.

Comment: This works, but is kind of dangerous because you're monkey-patching a very fundamental part of Ruby to work in a completely different way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still very fearful of monkey-patches!

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as:

```
name = params[:company] && params[:company][:owner] && params[:company][:owner][:name]
```

It's not as clean as the [? operator in Io](http://www.iolanguage.com/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html#Primitives-Object), but Ruby doesn't have that. The answer by @ThiagoSilveira is also good, though it will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to avoid using a multi-dimensional hash, and use

```
params[[:company, :owner, :name]]
```

or

```
params[[:company, :owner, :name]] if params.has_key?([:company, :owner, :name])
```

instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew. I'm not able to avoid the multi-dimensional hash (unfortunately) as the hash is being passed from an external library.

Answer (score 1):

Write the ugliness once, then hide it

```
def check_all_present(hash, keys)
  current_hash = hash
  keys.each do |key|
    return false unless current_hash[key]
    current_hash = current_hash[key]
  end
  true
end
```

Comment: I think this might be better and more useful to the OP (and common) needs if the return value was the last item in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
params.fetch('company', {}).fetch('owner', {})['name']
```

Also at each step, you can use an appropriate method built in `NilClass` to escape from `nil`, if it were array, string, or numeric. Just add `to_hash` to the inventory of this list and use it.

```
class NilClass; def to_hash; {} end end
params['company'].to_hash['owner'].to_hash['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

(Even though it's a really old question maybe this answer will be useful for some stackoverflow people like me that did not think of the "begin rescue" control structure expression.)

I would do it with a try catch statement (begin rescue in ruby language):

```
begin
    name = params[:company][:owner][:name]
rescue
    #if it raises errors maybe:
    name = 'John Doe'
end
```

Comment: And what if I typo name = parms[:company][:owner][:name]?  The code will happily go along with 'John Doe', and I may never notice.

Comment: That's true it should've been nil in the rescue case since thats what the question was using. I now see that Thiago Silveira's answer was exactly what i was thinking but more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need access to the original hash definition -- you can override the [] method on the fly after you get it using h.instance_eval, e.g.

```
h = {1 => 'one'}
h.instance_eval %q{
  alias :brackets :[]
  def [] key
    if self.has_key? key
      return self.brackets(key)
    else
      h = Hash.new
      h.default = {}
      return h
    end
  end
}
```

But that's not going to help you with the code you have, because you're relying on an unfound value to return a false value (e.g., nil) and if you do any of the "normal" auto-vivification stuff linked to above you're going to end up with an empty hash for unfound values, which evaluates as "true".

You could do something like this -- it only checks for defined values and returns them. You can't set them this way, because we've got no way of knowing if the call is on the LHS of an assignment.

```
module AVHash
  def deep(*args)
    first = args.shift
    if args.size == 0
      return self[first]
    else
      if self.has_key? first and self[first].is_a? Hash
        self[first].send(:extend, AVHash)
        return self[first].deep(*args)
      else
        return nil
      end
    end
  end
end      

h = {1=>2, 3=>{4=>5, 6=>{7=>8}}}
h.send(:extend, AVHash)
h.deep(0) #=> nil
h.deep(1) #=> 2
h.deep(3) #=> {4=>5, 6=>{7=>8}}
h.deep(3,4) #=> 5
h.deep(3,10) #=> nil
h.deep(3,6,7) #=> 8
```

Again, though, you can only check values with it -- not assign them. So it's not real auto-vivification as we all know and love it in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Dangerous but works:

```
class Object
        def h_try(key)
            self[key] if self.respond_to?('[]')
        end    
end
```

We can new do

```
   user = { 
     :first_name => 'My First Name', 
     :last_name => 'my Last Name', 
     :details => { 
        :age => 3, 
        :birthday => 'June 1, 2017' 
      } 
   }

   user.h_try(:first_name) # 'My First Name'
   user.h_try(:something) # nil
   user.h_try(:details).h_try(:age) # 3
   user.h_try(:details).h_try(:nothing).h_try(:doesnt_exist) #nil
```

The "h_try" chain follows similar style to a "try" chain.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; `params&.dig(:company, :owner, :name)`

As of Ruby 2.3.0:

You can also use `&.` called the "safe navigation operator" as: `params&.[](:company)&.[](:owner)&.[](:name)`. This one is perfectly safe.

Using `dig` on `params` is not actually safe as `params.dig` will fail if `params` is nil.

However you may combine the two as: `params&.dig(:company, :owner, :name)`.

So either of the following is safe to use:

`params&.[](:company)&.[](:owner)&.[](:name)`

`params&.dig(:company, :owner, :name)`

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer a one-up on `dig`, try the [KeyDial](https://github.com/ConvincibleMedia/ruby-gem-key_dial) gem which I wrote. This is essentially a wrapper for `dig` but with the important difference that it will never hit you with an error.

`dig` will still spit out an error if an object in the chain is of some type that can't itself be `dig`ed.

```
hash = {a: {b: {c: true}, d: 5}}

hash.dig(:a, :d, :c) #=> TypeError: Integer does not have #dig method
```

In this situation `dig` does not help you, and you need to go back not only to `hash[:a][:d].nil? &&` but also `hash[:a][:d].is_a?(Hash)` checks. KeyDial lets you do this without such checks or errors:

```
hash.call(:a, :d, :c) #=> nil
hash.call(:a, :b, :c) #=> true
```