# Equivalent of .try() for a hash to avoid "undefined method" errors on nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

In Rails we can do the following in case a value doesn't exist to avoid an error:

```
@myvar = @comment.try(:body)
```

What is the equivalent when I'm digging deep into a hash and don't want to get an error?

```
@myvar = session[:comments][@comment.id]["temp_value"] 
# [:comments] may or may not exist here
```

In the above case, `session[:comments]try[@comment.id]` doesn't work. What would?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/looking-for-a-good-way-to-avoid-hash-conditionals-in-ruby

Comment: Ruby 2.3 introduced `Hash#dig` that makes `try` unnecessary here. @baxang has the best answer now.

Comment: Dig does not make try unnexessary, because it sill fails on other objects than hash. For exaple nil. But using dig in combination with the save operator does => session&.dig(:comments, @comment.id, "temp_value")

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You forgot to put a `.` before the `try`:

```
@myvar = session[:comments].try(:[], @comment.id)
```

since `[]` is the name of the method when you do `[@comment.id]`.

Comment: Since `:[]` looks a little weird within `try`, you could also write this as `session[:comments].try(:fetch, @comment.id)`.

Comment: fetch throws an error if the key is not found, unless you pass a default. So you would need to write: session[:comments].try(:fetch, @comment.id, nil)

Comment: `try` is no longer necessary as of Ruby 2.3. @baxang has the best answer, below.

Comment: what if nil? I want to return [], instead of nil.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to ruby, what's :[] here?

Answer (score 76):

[The announcement of Ruby 2.3.0-preview1](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/11/11/ruby-2-3-0-preview1-released/) includes an introduction of Safe navigation operator.

> A safe navigation operator, which already exists in C#, Groovy, and
>   Swift, is introduced to ease nil handling as `obj&.foo`. `Array#dig` and
>   `Hash#dig` are also added.

This means as of 2.3 below code

```rb
account.try(:owner).try(:address)
```

can be rewritten to

```rb
account&.owner&.address
```

However, one should be careful that `&` is not a drop in replacement of `#try`. Take a look at this example:

```
> params = nil
nil
> params&.country
nil
> params = OpenStruct.new(country: "Australia")
#<OpenStruct country="Australia">
> params&.country
"Australia"
> params&.country&.name
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for "Australia":String
from (pry):38:in `<main>'
> params.try(:country).try(:name)
nil
```

It is also including a similar sort of way: `Array#dig` and `Hash#dig`. So now this

```rb
city = params.fetch(:[], :country).try(:[], :state).try(:[], :city)
```

can be rewritten to

```rb
city = params.dig(:country, :state, :city)
```

Again, `#dig` is not replicating `#try`'s behaviour. So be careful with returning values. If `params[:country]` returns, for example, an Integer, `TypeError: Integer does not have #dig method` will be raised.

Comment: breaks if the hash is `nil` for those who where wondering

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually work with a Rails session as ActionDispatch::Request::Session doesn't implement #dig

Comment: also breaks if `params[:country]` is not a `hash` or `nil` (e.g. a `string`)

Comment: &. does **not** break on `nil` (unlike `.dig` by itself). Therefore a safe implementation is: `params&.dig(:country, :state, :city)`

Answer (score 25):

The most beautiful solution is an old [answer by Mladen Jablanović](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/looking-for-a-good-way-to-avoid-hash-conditionals-in-ruby/4380514#4380514), as it lets you to dig in the hash deeper than you could with using direct `.try()` calls, if you want the code still look nice:

```
class Hash
  def get_deep(*fields)
    fields.inject(self) {|acc,e| acc[e] if acc}
  end
end
```

You should be careful with various objects (especially `params`), because Strings and Arrays also respond to :[], but the returned value may not be what you want, and Array raises exception for Strings or Symbols used as indexes.

That is the reason why in the **suggested form** of this method (below) the *(usually ugly)* test for `.is_a?(Hash)` is used instead of *(usually better)* `.respond_to?(:[])`:

```
class Hash
  def get_deep(*fields)
    fields.inject(self) {|acc,e| acc[e] if acc.is_a?(Hash)}
  end
end

a_hash = {:one => {:two => {:three => "asd"}, :arr => [1,2,3]}}

puts a_hash.get_deep(:one, :two               ).inspect # => {:three=>"asd"}
puts a_hash.get_deep(:one, :two, :three       ).inspect # => "asd"
puts a_hash.get_deep(:one, :two, :three, :four).inspect # => nil
puts a_hash.get_deep(:one, :arr            ).inspect    # => [1,2,3]
puts a_hash.get_deep(:one, :arr, :too_deep ).inspect    # => nil
```

The last example **would raise an exception**: "Symbol as array index (TypeError)" if it was not guarded by this ugly "is_a?(Hash)".

Comment: actually, since `nil` is not a `Hash` you can probably simplify to `fields.inject(self) {|acc,e| acc[e] if acc.is_a?(Hash)}` 
But I have a feeling `#respond_to`would be better.

Comment: @riffraff: You are perfectly right about that `acc & acc.is_a?()` - consider that a mistake ;-). But `respond_to` would not work, because String and a lot of other objects also respond to `:[]`, but the result of this method is **not** what is wanted here.

Comment: The point of using `object.try` is that `object` can be `nil`. Whereas in your case `nil.get_deep` will raise an exception. Your solution doesn't answer the question then.

Comment: The question says "when I'm digging deep into a hash", and I did not assume that a  `session` could be `nil`, but if it could, then it would be perfectly OK to call  `session.try(:get_deep, :comments, @comment.id, "temp_value")`

Answer (score 17):

The proper use of [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) with a hash is `@sesion.try(:[], :comments)`.

```
@session.try(:[], :comments).try(:[], commend.id).try(:[], 'temp_value')
```

Comment: -1 Why can't it be nested? `try` applies to any `Object`, and `nil` is an `Object`, so I suspect the following would work: `nil.try(:do).try(:do_not).try(:there_is_a_try)`.

Comment: The "cant be nested" is wrong. But for your particular case my appreciation was correct. what you need to do is use try with :[], for use it with the key directly you need to use fetch.

Answer (score 17):

***Update:*** As of Ruby 2.3 use [#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)

Most objects that respond to [] expect an Integer argument, with Hash being an exception that will accept any object (such as strings or symbols).

The following is a slightly more robust version of [Arsen7's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225321/199685) that supports nested Array, Hash, as well as any other objects that expect an Integer passed to [].

It's not fool proof, as someone may have created an object that implements [] and *does not* accept an Integer argument. However, this solution works great in the common case e.g. pulling nested values from JSON (which has both Hash and Array):

```
class Hash
  def get_deep(*fields)
    fields.inject(self) { |acc, e| acc[e] if acc.is_a?(Hash) || (e.is_a?(Integer) && acc.respond_to?(:[])) }
  end
end
```

It can be used the same as Arsen7's solution but also supports arrays e.g.

```
json = { 'users' => [ { 'name' => { 'first_name' => 'Frank'} }, { 'name' => { 'first_name' => 'Bob' } } ] }

json.get_deep 'users', 1, 'name', 'first_name' # Pulls out 'Bob'
```

Answer (score 14):

```
@myvar = session.fetch(:comments, {}).fetch(@comment.id, {})["temp_value"]
```

From Ruby 2.0, you can do:

```
@myvar = session[:comments].to_h[@comment.id].to_h["temp_value"]
```

From Ruby 2.3, you can do:

```
@myvar = session.dig(:comments, @comment.id, "temp_value")
```

Comment: because that's not what `.try` does.

Comment: Looks like session doesn't implement dig:
undefined method `dig' for #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x007ffc6cafa698>

Answer (score 14):

say you want to find `params[:user][:email]` but it's not sure whether `user` is there in `params` or not. Then-

you can try:

```
params[:user].try(:[], :email)
```

It will return either **`nil`**(if `user` is not there or `email` is not there in `user`) or otherwise the value of `email` in `user`.

Answer (score 14):

As of Ruby 2.3 this gets a little easier. Instead of having to nest `try` statements or define your own method you can now use `Hash#dig` ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig)).

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot)                 #=> nil
```

Or in the example above:

```
session.dig(:comments, @comment.id, "temp_value")
```

This has the added benefit of being more like `try` than some of the examples above. If any of the arguments lead to the hash returning nil then it will respond nil.

Comment: Can't use dig on the session hash

Comment: Best answer, working okay with regular hashes

Answer (score 8):

Another approach:

```
@myvar = session[:comments][@comment.id]["temp_value"] rescue nil
```

This might also be consider a bit dangerous because it can hide too much, personally I like it.

If you want more control, you may consider something like:

```
def handle # just an example name, use what speaks to you
    raise $! unless $!.kind_of? NoMethodError # Do whatever checks or 
                                              # reporting you want
end
# then you may use
@myvar = session[:comments][@comment.id]["temp_value"] rescue handle
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
myhash[:one][:two][:three]
```

You're just chaining a bunch of calls to a "[]" method, an the error occurs if myhash[:one] returns nil, because nil doesn't have a [] method.  So, one simple and rather hacky way is to add a [] method to Niclass, which returns nil: i would set this up in a rails app as follows:

Add the method:

```
#in lib/ruby_extensions.rb
class NilClass
  def [](*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

Require the file:

```
#in config/initializers/app_environment.rb
require 'ruby_extensions'
```

Now you can call nested hashes without fear: i'm demonstrating in the console here:

```
>> hash = {:foo => "bar"}
=> {:foo=>"bar"}
>> hash[:foo]
=> "bar"
>> hash[:doo]
=> nil
>> hash[:doo][:too]
=> nil
```

Comment: This is fascinating - thanks Max! Are there any disadvantages to this you know of? Does anyone else have a perspective on this?

Comment: It will hide your problems with unexpected nils in other parts of your code. I would consider this method dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer didn't work for me when I tried this again recently. Maybe something has changed?

```
@myvar = session[:comments].try('[]', @comment.id)
```

The `'[]'` is in quotes instead of a symbol `:[]`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
@myvar = session[:comments][@comment.id]["temp_value"] if session[:comments]
```

Comment: how about if I don't know if either `[:comments]` or `[@comment.id]` exist?

Comment: in this case I think it would be better to create nested IF statements to check every parameter in session

Comment: @sscirrus: You could do `session[:comments][@comment.id]["temp_value"] if (session[:comments] and session[:comments][@comment.id])`

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - yeah, I figured that would work but I was hoping for something more concise (I would have a few similar expressions in one place, and it looks very code-heavy). I like your actual answer. :)