# How to access an element deep in an array of arrays without getting 'undefined method' error

Tags: ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

When trying to access an element deep in an array of arrays, what is the best way to avoid getting the error 'undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass' if an element doesn't exist?

For example I'm currently doing this, but it seems bad to me:

```
if @foursquare['response']['groups'][0].present? && @foursquare['response']['groups'][0]['items'].present?
```

Comment: Don't you mean a hash of hashes, not an array of arrays?

Comment: Closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224875/equivalent-of-try-for-a-hash/6224980#6224980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your array content, you can omit the `.present?`. Ruby will also just take the last value in such a construct, so you can omit the `if` statement.

```
@foursquare['response']['groups'][0] &&
@foursquare['response']['groups'][0]['items'] &&
@foursquare['response']['groups'][0]['items'][42]
```

More elegant solutions for this problem are the [egonil](https://github.com/janlelis/egonil) ([blog post](https://rbjl.janlelis.com/26-the-28-bytes-of-ruby-joy)), the [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) gem ([blog post](https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2009-02-02/hopeless_egocentricity.md)), or even Ruby 2.3's [safe navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537).

**Update:** Recent Rubies include the `#dig` method, which might be helpful in this case. See [user513951](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623778/169793)'s answer for more details.

Comment: I've wound up using this for now: `if @foursquare['response']['groups'].try(:[], 0).try(:[], 'items').present?`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 2.3.0 introduced [a new method called `dig`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-dig) on both `Hash` and `Array` that can be combined with the new safe navigation operator (`&.`) to solve your problem.

```
@foursquare.dig('response', 'groups')&.first&.dig('items')
```

This will return `nil` if a value is missing at any level.

Comment: now that's a way to leverage an answer a few times :P

Answer (score 2):

```
if @foursquare['response']['groups'][0].to_a['items']
  . . .
```

It happens that `NilClass` implements a `#to_a` that returns `[].`  This means that you can map every `nil` to `[]` and typically write a single expression without tests.