# Ruby 1.9.2 non-existent hash element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on Rails 3.0.x, Ruby 1.9.2 and needs a way to test for params that may or may not exists, e.g.,

```
params[:user] #exists
params[:user][:login] #may not exist
```

What's the proper Ruby syntax for the 2nd check so it doesn't barf?

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/looking-for-a-good-way-to-avoid-hash-conditionals-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
params.has_key? :user #=> true because exists
params[:user].has_key? :login #=> true if exist otherwise false
```

Comment: Nice suggestion but that doesn't work because `params[:user]' first returns it as as string in which case it is no longer a hash and hence no `has_key?` method.

Answer (score 1):

@WarHog has it right, pretty much. It's very unusual for an item in `params` to sometimes return a string but other times return a Hash, but regardless you can handle that easily enough:

```
if params.has_key?(:user) && params[:user].respond_to?(:has_key?)
  do_something_with params[:user][:login]
end
```

Instead of `respond_to? :has_key?` you could also do `respond_to? :[]` or just `is_a? Hash`. Mostly a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

**You would just get nil in the second case**.. that shouldn't be a problem, no? 
e.g. `params[:user][:login]` just returns nil, which evaluates to false if the :user entry exists in the first Hash.

However if the nesting would be one or more levels deeper, and the missing hash entry was somewhere in the middle, you would have problems.  e.g.:

```
params[:user][:missing_key][:something]
```

in that case Ruby would try to evaluate nil[:something] and raise an exception

you could do something like this:

```
begin
  x = params[:user][:missing_key][:something]
rescue
  x = nil
end
```

... which you could further abstract...