# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810311/nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass)

I am new to rails 3, and I am trying to render something to an HTML form:

```
<td class="kanban-task-handler">by: <%=h (!@tasks[activity['taskid']]['assignee'].nil? ? @tasks[activity['taskid']]['assignee'] : '') %></td>
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

but I'm checking this variable and stating if it's nil--> then print out nothing...
so why isn't this working?

Comment: Could you tell us how your data looks like? You have a Task, Activity models? What's @tasks and activity in your code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but it seems like @tasks is nil here. You could just check it with @tasks.nil?

But remember, if the @tasks is an array it will not give you nil? -> true instead you need to use <`Array`>.empty?

A safer way of checking this is:

```
@task.try(:attribute).try(:attribute2) etc
```

Comment: activity could also be nil??

Comment: But using try in views is not good! At least I try to avoid it... Also it's a hint that you are falling the Law of Demeter

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should model it in a different way.

Why you do `@tasks[activity['taskid']]['assignee']`in the first place ???

You should be able to do something like `activity.assignee` or `activity.task.assignee``

I guess you have a Activity, Task and Assignee model. Ok, maybe you don't have Assignee.

But with the first 2 you could do something like this, and following to the [Law of Demeter](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/15-the-law-of-demeter) you shouldn't call methods of more than one class.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities

  def assignee_name
    try(:assignee) || 'No assignee' # or ''
  end
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task

  delegate :assignee_name, to: :task
end
```

Now you could this

```
<td class="kanban-task-handler">by: <%=h ativity.assignee_name %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say try:

`td class="kanban-task-handler">by: <%=h (!@tasks[activity['taskid']]['assignee']) or ""%></td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rescue` keyword to handle exception in the same line, try this

```
<td class="kanban-task-handler">by: <%=h (@tasks[activity['taskid']]['assignee'] rescue '') %></td>
```