# How to catch an "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get an nested array from facebook via omniauth and wanna check if it's empty?/nil?/exists?
the depending line looks like:

```
 unless omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['location']['name'].nil?
```

This should check if this part of the array is empty or exists.

But always this error was thrown:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Do I check arrays wrong?

I tried it with "has_key" "nil?" "empty?" "exists?" "blank?"

But no one of these works!

Please help me, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but, as pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623680/3284936), Ruby 2.3.0 [introduced a new method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) called `dig`, which would return `nil` if one of the chained keys is `nil`. Your omniauth auth hash could then be presented as:

```
omniauth = { 
            ...                 
            "extra"=>{ "raw_info"=>
                        { "location"=>"New York",
                          "gravatar_id"=>"123456789"}}
             ...
           }


omniauth.dig('extra', 
             'raw_info',
             'location',
             'name',
             'foo',
             'bar',
             'baz') #<= nil
```

Comment: Or `omniauth.dig(*%w[extra raw_info location name foo bar baz])` if all the internal punctuation is hard to read.

Answer (score 15):

Ideally you should check each nested level to see if it is `nil`, however, this will also work.

```
unless (omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['location']['name'] rescue nil).nil?
```

You can also rescue the `NoMethodError` specifically.

Answer (score 13):

This error is raised because one of the hash values in the chain of `omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['location']['name'].nil?` returns nil and it is not the last call ['name'].

If for example `omniauth['extra']['raw_info']` returns nil, you're actually trying to call `nil['location']` which raises an error in ruby.

You can catch this error simply:

```
res = omniauth['extra']['raw_info']['location']['name'].nil? rescue true

unless res
  #your code here
end
```

Please notice that the code block above will fill the variable res with true if the ['name'] hash value is nil or any other hash value in the chain returns nil.

Comment: Hi Erez,

thank you, but how can I say "if you are nil..." execute the next lines?

Comment: if res is true - one of the omniauth hash values returned nil

Comment: I'm late to the game, but I recommend against this methodology, as it will catch any exception in the line, for any reason.  In this scenario, you are fairly limited on what would get returned, however this would start to fail if you were using a method to determine the value of `omniauth`.  Then you won't know why it's failing.  In general, blanket rescue is bad practice.