# how to read individual data from the content of remote JSON file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I am trying to read individual data from the content of *json API* on Oil and Gas Authority website; however the code I have returns all the data. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

def index
  url='http://data-ogauthority.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ab4f6b9519794522aa6ffa6c31617bf8_0.geojson'
  @result = JSON.parse open(url).read
end
```

This my index view:

```
<% @result.each do |row| %>
  <%= row %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is your problem (a) that your `@result` variable has more data than you want (i.e., you want to get more targeted data back from the API call) or (b) that you are having trouble extracting the data you want from your `@result` variable?

Comment: yes I want to get more targeted data from the API call

Comment: Your question, then, isn't a `ruby-on-rails` question (nor a `json` or `ruby` question). It's an ArcGIS question.

Comment: What specific data are you trying to get?

Comment: Data on field name, field type, status, discovery data and discovery well.

Comment: Check [this](https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/OGA_Public_WGS84/OGA_Offshore_Fields_WGS84/MapServer/0/query) out, it might help filter from source.

Comment: Also instead of default [ruby JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) you can use [Oj gem](https://github.com/ohler55/oj). Its much faster and more preferable choice if you have lots of json decoding/encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the API (as you are currently using it) returns a JSON structure like this:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
        "FIELDNAME":"GRYPHON",
        "FIELDTYPE":"OIL",
        "NAME_SHORT":"GRYPHON",
        "STATUS":"PRODUCING",
        "DISC_DATE":"1987/07",
        "DISC_WELL":"9/18b-7",
        "STAT_CODE":"800",
        "PROD_DATE":"1993/10",
        "DEPTH_M":"111.86",
        "DET_STATUS":"DETERMINED",
        "ORIG_OP":"KERR-MCGEE",
        "ORIG_LIC":"P.496",
        "ORIG_LIC_2":"P.478",
        "ORIG_LIC_3":"P.257",
        "ORIG_LIC_4":"P.103",
        "ORIG_LIC_5":" ",
        "CURR_OPER":"MAERSK OIL NORTH SEA UK LIMITED",
        "FIELDDATA":"https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/fields/fields_index/ukcs+field+information+listed+by+field+name/183.htm",
        "OBJECTID":16,
        "OGA_COP":null
      },
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[
          [
            [1.5701447246411744,59.35253688325039],
            ...
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

You could do something like:

```
<% @result[:features].each do |feature| %>
  <%= feature[:properties][:FIELDNAME] %>
  <%= feature[:properties][:FIELDTYPE] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Your JSON file looks to be something like 1.3MB. So, unless you can figure out how to filter your results on the API side (using query params, I would suppose), you may end up with various performance issues in retrieving the JSON.

And, you may want to do:

```
@result = JSON.parse(open(url).read).with_indifferent_access
```

So that you can use `symbols` to access `hash` elements as well as `strings`.

Comment: Thanks Guys everything works fine but am also trying to keep the data in my database how should go about that.

Comment: @fred if you are using posgres > 9.3, there is a `JSON` column type. Otherwise you can use `text` and use Rails `serialize` method. Take a look at this article from CodeShip: https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/

Answer (score 1):

One thing to add to @jvillian answer is that if one of the keys is `nil` then calling this branch's subsequent keys will result in `undefined method '[]'`. Ruby 2.3+ has a new method called `dig` which will simply return `nil`. More on `dig` in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985286/3284936) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11501992/3284936).

Comment: Great addition. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to [@jvillian answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785191/6136634), you can fetch the filtered information using [this link](https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/OGA_Public_WGS84/OGA_Offshore_Fields_WGS84/MapServer/0/query); for example, taking into account the fields you need:

- FIELDNAME
- FIELDTYPE
- STATUS
- DISC_DATE
- DISC_WELL

You could create [query](https://itportal.decc.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/OGA_Public_WGS84/OGA_Offshore_Fields_WGS84/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=FIELDNAME%2C%20FIELDTYPE%2C%20STATUS%2C%20DISC_DATE%2C%20DISC_WELL&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson) that will result in the following response:

```
{
 "displayFieldName": "FIELDNAME",
 "fieldAliases": {
  "FIELDNAME": "Field Name",
  "FIELDTYPE": "Field Type",
  "STATUS": "Status",
  "DISC_DATE": "Discovery Date",
  "DISC_WELL": "Discovery Well"
 },
 "fields": [
  {
   "name": "FIELDNAME",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "Field Name",
   "length": 32
  },
  {
   "name": "FIELDTYPE",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "Field Type",
   "length": 4
  },
  {
   "name": "STATUS",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "Status",
   "length": 50
  },
  {
   "name": "DISC_DATE",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "Discovery Date",
   "length": 20
  },
  {
   "name": "DISC_WELL",
   "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
   "alias": "Discovery Well",
   "length": 20
  }
 ],
 "features": [
  {
   "attributes": {
    "FIELDNAME": "GRYPHON",
    "FIELDTYPE": "OIL",
    "STATUS": "PRODUCING",
    "DISC_DATE": "1987/07",
    "DISC_WELL": "9/18b-7"
   }
  },
  {
   "attributes": {
    "FIELDNAME": "BRAEMAR",
    "FIELDTYPE": "COND",
    "STATUS": "PRODUCING",
    "DISC_DATE": "1995/05",
    "DISC_WELL": "16/03b-8Z"
   }
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

This file will be now **76KB**, and you can extract the data in almost the same way, just change `properties` for `attributes`, i.e.:

```
<% @result[:features].each do |feature| %>
  <%= feature[:attributes][:FIELDNAME] %>
  <%= feature[:attributes][:FIELDTYPE] %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Guys everything works fine now but am also trying to keep the data in my database how should go about that.

Comment: @fred Glad to help! Please don't forget to accept the answer that worked for you (by clicking on the tick) and, if other answers also helped, you can upvote them (by clicking the up arrow).  :)

Comment: @fred About your question, in general, you could create a model and iterate through the data you receive creating  a record each time. I will suggest you to post a new question, that way you will get more detalied answers and more people will see it.