# Check if hash is nil before checking specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What I'm currently doing is

```
"Hello" if options && options[:greet]
```

What I would like to do is cut that line down. If `options` is nil, `options[:greet]` obviously will be too. Does Ruby/Rails provide a method that offers this "hash checking" ability? Or perhaps there's a way of writing this more succinctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid NoMethodError for missing elements in nested hashes, without repeated nil checks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/how-to-avoid-nomethoderror-for-missing-elements-in-nested-hashes-without-repeat)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate - multi-level nested hashes is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 7):

There's also one more shortcut, I tend to use it more often, when I don't have control over `options` variable (i.e. it may be either nil or hash):

```
options.to_h[:greet] # just convert it to a hash before key access
```

Note, that it works only [starting from Ruby 2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_h).

Answer (score 6):

I would argue that that line is perfectly fine.

Perhaps it might make sense to ensure that `options` are always set. If the `options` are passed in as a parameter to a method, you might want to set a default:

```
def method_name(options = {})
```

Or you might want to initialize `options` with an empty hash if `nil` before you start using them:

```
options ||= {}
```

Ruby on Rails also offers the `try` method that does not fail when you call methods on `nil`:

```
options.try([], :greet)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was initializing with `options=nil`, and didn't really think about the possibility of setting it to an empty hash. Interesting use of `try` too :)